# Turtle graphics - trying to get a background image fails?

Tags: python, background, turtle-graphics

I have been using turtle graphics (python and pycharm) and have gotten to a point where I want to include a background image.  When I try to use the code

```
turtle.bgpic("bkgrd.jpg")
```

it gives me this error :

```
couldn't recognize data in image file "bkgrd.jpg"
```

Here is the code snippet (not the entire code):

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()
turtle.setup(500,500)
turtle.bgpic("bkgrd.jpg")
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Without the line turtle.bgpic(), this runs and creates a blank window. I have tried this with gif and png as well.  the graphic files are in the same directory at the python file (using pycharm).  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Go back to using your *.gif file:

```
> python3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> help(turtle.bgpic)
Help on function bgpic in module turtle:

bgpic(picname=None)
    Set background image or return name of current backgroundimage.

    Optional argument:
    picname -- a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic".

    If picname is a filename, set the corresponding image as background.
    If picname is "nopic", delete backgroundimage, if present.
    If picname is None, return the filename of the current backgroundimage.

    Example:
    >>> bgpic()
    'nopic'
    >>> bgpic("landscape.gif")
    >>> bgpic()
    'landscape.gif'

>>>
```

As you can see from the documentation it's GIF or nothing.  If your *.gif file doesn't work, update your question with your modifed code (that uses a *.gif file) and a link to the *.gif file itself.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the gif that was causing the issue.  It now works.  Any idea on how to center the image in the window?